# React - queue for loading pictures with possibility to change it

Tags: reactjs, queue, loading

How can I make a queue for loading pictures in React? In fact, for React VR but in most cases, it should be same for both I think - one bigger difference is probably that I can't use Webpack. Important for me is also that I want to be able to change it during loading. For example, I have 5 really big pictures, we have already loaded first and the second but user click on picture number 4 so instead of 3 it should start loading this one.

Comment: Maybe https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-queue helps you. I wrote it because I have similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of handling this kind of asynchronous process is using promises.

Maybe you have an array of links from which to load the images

```
const imagesURLs = [ /* a list of URLs */ ]
```

You could then do a function that asynchronously retrivers the images

```
function loadAllImagesStartingFrom(index, imagesURLS) {
     if (index >= imagesURLS.length) return;
     someImageRetrivingPromise(imagesURLS[index])
         .then(res => {
            /* do something with the image */
            loadAllImagesStartingFrom(index + 1, imagesURLS);
         });
}
```

so where you want to cause all the images to be loaded you could call

```
loadAllImagesStartingFrom(0, imagesURLs);
```

and indipendently call `someImageRetrivingPromise` when you have to retrive an image if it has not still been loaded (you should make a check first).

The only problem of this aproach is that if an image have not been loaded and you load it separately then it gets loaded in the "queue" too, so there would be a double call, but you could make a check in `loadAllImagesStartingFrom` before `someImageRetrivingPromise` if the image have alredy been loaded then call `loadAllImages(index + 1, imagesURLS);` instead of the promise.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this soon and will wire results ;)